# How to do a one-line dict delete operation

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Is there a way to do the following in one line?

```
[del item for item in new_json if item['Country'] in countries_to_remove]
```

The above gives me a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Please add example data. What input do you have, what output do you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`del` is a statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) and you cannot use that [as an expression in list comprehenstion](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-comprehension). That is why you are getting a `SyntaxError`.

You can use list comprehension to create a new list, without the elements you don't want, like this

```
[item for item in new_json if item['Country'] not in countries_to_remove]
```

This is actually equivalent to,

```
result = []
for item in new_json:
    if item['Country'] not in countries_to_remove:
        result.append(item)
```

---

This kind of operation is called filtering a list and you can use the builtin `filter` function, like this

```
list(filter(lambda x: x['Country'] not in countries_to_remove, new_json))
```

---

As suggested by [mgilson in the comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552570/how-to-do-a-one-line-dict-delete-operation/31552586#comment51063286_31552586), if you just want to mutate the original list, then you can use slicing assignment, like this

```
new_json[:] = [x for x in new_json if x['Country'] not in countries_to_remove]
```

Comment: And, if you need to do the operation in place, you can use slice-assignment:  `new_json[:] = [item for item in ...]`

Answer (score 4):

[`del`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-del-statement) is a statement in python, and you cannot have statements inside list comprehension (You can only have expressions there). Why not just create `new_json` as a new list or dictionary that does not include the items you want to delete. Example =

```
new_json = [item for item in new_json if item['Country'] not in countries_to_remove]
```

Comment: Good idea, that's what I ended up doing.